# How to filter a list variable of an object in java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an object `Student`

```
public class Student {
   String name;
   String[] classes;

    public Student(String name, String[] classes){
        this.name = name;
        this.classes = classes;
    }

   //getter & setter
}
```

I want to filter the classes. For example, I have

```
Student sa = new Student("John", "math, physics")
Student sb = new Student("Jack", "math, english")
Student sc = new Student("Maria", "math, chemistry")
```

So how do I get the `Student` with `math` vairable? Do I need to write a new Predicate or is there an existing method? Thank you.

Comment: Build a stream from that array and filter by that "term".

Comment: write the getter and use streams lambda with filter method

Comment: You can't just create an array from "math, physics", you need to do something like new String[]{"math", "physics"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

First: If your constructor requires a `String[]` parameter, you have to provide a `String[]` not a `String`. Call it like this:

```
Student sa = new Student("John", new String[]{"math", "physics"});
Student sb = new Student("Jack", new String[]{"math", "english"});
Student sc = new Student("Maria", new String[]{"math", "chemistry"});
```

You *should* make your fields private and use getters, instead of making them package private. You can read about visibility [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Now, you have three `Student` objecs. You cant put them into a Stream the easiest way like this:

```
Arrays.stream(new Student[]{sa, sb, sc})
```

You can now filter the stream with something like this:

```
Arrays.stream(new Student[]{sa, sb, sc})
    .filter(s -> {
        for(String className : s.classes) {
            if(className.equals("math")) return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
```

Which will give you a Stream of all Students that have the class `math` within their `classes` field. You can now collect your elements or do more work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a seaparate `find` method to locate a class in the array:

```
List<Student> mathStudents = studentList.stream()
                  .filter(student -> findClass(student.getClasses(), "math"))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sorting is needed for binary search, but it's better done before the search, preferably in constructor of `Student`, as [suggested by AlexH](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/87220926?noredirect=1)

```
private static boolean findClass(String[] classes, String search) {

    Arrays.sort(classes); 
    return 0 <= Arrays.binarySearch(classes, search);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to sort the array in `Student` constructor. This would be simpler to look at `chemistry` later on ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `List<Student>` populated with the correct data, you can accomplish the task at hand like so:

```
List<Student> result = 
     students.stream()
             .filter(student -> Arrays.stream(student.getClasses())
                                      .anyMatch("math"::equals))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This creates a stream from the list of students and filters them to retain only students who have a "math" class.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could I ask how to filter two classes such as `math` and `physics`? Thanks!

Comment: @DexD.Hunter no probs and sure, you can do it like this --> `List<Student> result =
                students.stream()
                        .filter(s -> {
                            Set<String> classes =Set.of(s.getClasses());
                            return  classes.contains("math") && classes.contains("physics");
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @DexD.Hunter if you're not using java-9 then change `Set<String> classes =Set.of(s.getClasses());` to `List<String> classes = Arrays.asList(s.getClasses());`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!